# how to find if a number has a representation in a this format?

Tags: java, math, numbers

I better explain this problem with an example ,100 would be represented as 983 because 9^1 + 8^2 + 3^3 is one hundred, what i don't understand is how do i  find a relation between 100 and 9 and its power (1) or 100 and 8 its power 2 .
 so i want a piece of  code that works as follows

```
int [] allowedNumbers={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};//numbers that are allowed to be used to represent n in the specified format
boolean has_a_representation (int n)
{
//code to find if a number can be represented or not in the specified format
//return true or false
}
Sysout.out.println (has_a_representation (100));//will output true because 100 can be represented as 983
```

Comment: Are you asking how to solve this with a program? Because StackOverflow is for specific program questions, not math formulas or tutorials. Have you attempted to solve this yet in any language?

Comment: Well, what is the exact question? I am not sure what you want to show. A mathematical proof? A piece of to compute the answer? What are the restrictions? If I understood that correctly, can the number 100 be represented as 3902?

Comment: If you're looking for a programmatic solution, it can be easily achieved in Javascript through loops, but again, I would highly suggest you either redefine the scope of your question into a programming problem or ask it on another StackExchange site.

Comment: Hint: do this recursively. Try each allowed number, and try each possible exponent. Raise the number to that exponent, subtract the resulting power, and see whether the rest can be represented. Make sure you don't raise two numbers to the same exponent.

Comment: @QuakeCore: Not sure where you got your idea of 100000 numbers from, but I'm talking about a fraction of a second runtime here.

Comment: @MvG lets say that my representation set is from (2 to 7) and i want to find the representation of 25 then i would have to check for all the  permutations of my representation set right ? and even worse... or this is at least how i understand your proposed solutiong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive approach. If you can have zeros (i.e. don't have to use all exponents), you can do this:

```
boolean has_a_representation(int n) {
    return has_a_representation(n, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
boolean has_a_representation(int n, int max_exponent) {
    if (n == 0)
        return true;
    for (int digit: allowedNumbers) {
        int power = digit;
        for (int exp = 1; exp < max_exponent && power <= n; ++exp) {
            if (has_a_representation(n - power, exp))
                return true;
            power *= digit;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you have to use all exponents, it becomes even easier and faster:

```
boolean has_a_representation(int n) {
    return has_a_representation(n, 1);
}
boolean has_a_representation(int n, int exp) {
    for (int digit: allowedNumbers) {
        int power = digit;
        for (int i = 1; i < exp; ++i)
            power *= digit;
        if (n == power)
            return true;
        if (n < power) // allowedNumbers must be sorted
            break;
        if (has_a_representation(n - power, exp + 1))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Some results from that latter code, augmented to collect the digits:

- 100 = 2<sup>1</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>4</sup>
- 25 = 8<sup>1</sup> + 8<sup>1</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup>
- 19 = 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup>
- 100000 = 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + 4<sup>4</sup> + 3<sup>5</sup> + 4<sup>6</sup> + 4<sup>7</sup> + 2<sup>8</sup> + 3<sup>9</sup> + 3<sup>10</sup>
- 1234567 = 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 4<sup>4</sup> + 6<sup>5</sup> + 5<sup>6</sup> + 5<sup>7</sup> + 4<sup>8</sup> + 3<sup>9</sup> + 2<sup>10</sup> + 2<sup>11</sup> + 2<sup>12</sup> + 2<sup>13</sup> + 2<sup>14</sup> + 2<sup>15</sup> + 2<sup>16</sup> + 2<sup>17</sup> + 2<sup>18</sup> + 2<sup>19</sup>
- 234567 = 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 6<sup>4</sup> + 9<sup>5</sup> + 5<sup>6</sup> + 5<sup>7</sup> + 3<sup>8</sup> + 2<sup>9</sup> + 3<sup>10</sup> + 2<sup>11</sup> + 2<sup>12</sup> + 2<sup>13</sup>

As you can see, this prefers smaller numbers. If you don't want that, you'd have to reverse the `allowedNumbers` array and adapt the `n < power` code path.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have coded after brooding over a bit on your problem.This can work for any number.Actually,the code just raises each digit in the input value to the power equal to it's position in the number,adds them up,and displays the result.For example,if the input is 34, the processing will be (3^1)+(4^2) and the output will thus be 3+16=19.This is how it works.
Here is the code:-

```
import java.util.*;
class Enc{
    void disp(int no){
    int p=dig(no);
    int arr[]=new int[p];
    for(int j=0;j<p;j++)
    arr[j]=j+1;
    int i=0;
    int k=no,sum=0;
    int num=rev(no);
    while(i<p)
    {
        sum+=Math.pow((num%10),arr[i]);
        i++;
        num/=10;
    }
    System.out.println("The number is:-"+sum);
}
int rev(int b){
    int mc=b,lo=0;
    while(mc>0)
    {
        lo=(lo*10)+(mc%10);
        mc/=10;
    }
    return lo;
}
int dig(int q){
    int jk=q,sum1=0;
    while(jk>0)
    {
        sum1++;
        jk/=10;
    }
    return sum1;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    Enc ob=new Enc();
    try{
        System.out.println("Enter the number in encrypted form:-");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        ob.disp(n);
    }catch(InputMismatchException exc){exc.printStackTrace();}
}
}
```

Comment: oh i accidentally gave you a vote up :), i want the opposite my friend i send the number and get the representation , but note that numbers like 25 has no representation if the number set used for representation was from (2 to 7)

Comment: Actually,100 can be represented as 983 as well as 86.Let me know the question clearly.Do you want to get the encrypted form of the number which is nearest to the input value?If that is the case,I would surely code it fore you.